# How do I get count of list item collection items with javascript?

Tags: javascript, client-object-model

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting a count of list items in a list via ECMAScript](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/5477/getting-a-count-of-list-items-in-a-list-via-ecmascript)

I found something, it works, but it's not nice.
var items;
...
var enumerator = items.getEnumerator();
var count = enumerator.$1k_0;

Comment: The same question here.  http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/5477/getting-a-count-of-list-items-in-a-list-via-ecmascript