# How to get the count of list items using javascript?

Tags: javascript, client-object-model

I want to count the list items using javascript

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/5477/getting-a-count-of-list-items-in-a-list-via-ecmascript?rq=1

Answer (score 5):

Use following code:

```
var oList;
function theFunction() {
    clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    web = clientContext.get_web();
    var oList = web.get_lists().getByTitle("Absences");

    // .load() tells CSOM to load the properties of this object
    // multiple .load()s can be stacked
    clientContext.load(oList);

    // now start the asynchronous call and perform all commands
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onFail);
    // method will exit here and onSuccess or OnFail will be called asynchronously
}
function onSuccess(sender, args) {
    alert('No of rows: ' + oList.get_itemCount());
}
function onFail(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed.\n' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

You can also try : http://sharepointdotnetwiki.iblogger.org/2012/09/using-jquery-to-get-total-items-in-sharepoint-list/

Comment: You have a bug in that code, you can not redeclare oList again within `theFunction`, because then the global oList that onSuccess is accessing is different and empty.

Answer (score 1):

You got the answer with Microsoft API, also one with SPServices. Let me add an answer with my JavaScript library called [SharepointPlus](http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/):

```
$SP().list("Your List Name").get({fields:"ID"}, function(data) {
  alert("Number of items: "+data.length)
})
```