# Web part page arrows showing Of how many (Total count of list items)

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, paging

I'm hoping one of you are able to help.  One of my users asked to see the Of XX for the page tabs.  So they know if they're on 10-20 of 1000 or 50.  I've been searching around for some time without any luck.  Is there a setting for this somewhere or is it a code item I need to embed.

[image: Web Part page tabs]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the main concern of this user is knowing the **total** items number/ list item count!

**Unfortunately**, **no** setting in the paging list to do that! but you can

- Show list item count by modifying your view and total it by count as shown below:

  [image]
- Another option, you get the **list items count using JSOM**,  and add it in Screipt editor web part in your page

  ```
  list.get_itemCount();
  ```

---

**Check the full sample at**

- [Getting a count of list items in a list via ECMAScript](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/5477/getting-a-count-of-list-items-in-a-list-via-ecmascript)
- [Get the count of items in a list using Javascript](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8f346191-2aa2-4c4d-bb29-39ce597ddb98/get-the-count-of-items-in-a-list-using-javascript?forum=sharepointgeneral)